# How is the xfer2 function used to read registers using SpiDev?

Tags: python, spi

I'm trying to communicate with my mpu9250 through SPI using the py-spidev module and I'm unable to understand how exactly the read function works.

I found this function snippet that performs the read register function and I'd like to know why the `__READ_FLAG` (`__READ_FLAG` = 0x80) is concatenated with the address byte for sending the dummy values to. Won't this change the register address completely?

```py
def ReadReg(self, reg_address):
    self.bus.open(self.spi_bus_number, self.spi_dev_number)
    tx = [reg_address | self.__READ_FLAG, 0x00]
    rx = self.bus.xfer2(tx)
    self.bus.close()
    return rx[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for this in another datasheet that follows the same protocol.

> Writing is done by lowering CSB and sending pairs control bytes and register data. The control
>   bytes consist of the SPI register address (= full register address without bit 7) and the write
>   command (bit7 = RW = ‘0’). Several pairs can be written without raising CSB. The transaction is
>   ended by a raising CSB.
>
> Reading is done by lowering CSB and first sending one control byte. The control bytes consist
>   of the SPI register address (= full register address without bit 7) and the read command (bit 7 =
>   RW = ‘1’). After writing the control byte, data is sent out of the SDO pin (SDI in 3-wire mode);
>   the register address is automatically incremented.

Comment: Can you share where you found this information?